# How to print the digit number of column in awk

Tags: awk

Suppose this file (delimiter is space):

```
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
this    |       |       |       |       |       |       is      -       -       -       -       good
that    |       |       |       |       |       |       not     -       -       -       -       bad
```

I want to print only `col1` and `col2` for example, but as I learnt up to now from `awk`, I use this by counting manually from `col1` as `$1` to `col2` as `$8`:

```
awk '{print $1, $8}' file
```

The expected output:

```
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       8       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

I mean to use `head -1 file | awk SOMETHING` to print only the first line and then print the number of each header has.

I mean I use an `awk` command to check the column number, then I use my `awk '{print $1, $8}'` command better and without counting manually each column number.

I googled and there were some `NFR` which don't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: `awk '{print NF}' file`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print column contents by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846300/print-column-contents-by-column-name)

Comment: @Cyrus no, it only prints the number `13`, but my desired output is from 1 to the last number (from 1 to 13).

Comment: @Barmar no, that doesn't.

Comment: It is unclear what you want.

Comment: @Cyrus I just want to print the number of each column, for example I want to know what's the position of `col2` and then print that column number. But I don't want to use `-v` or create a variable.

Comment: Why doesn't it do what you want? It tells how to get the column number of each column name. Then you can print those.

Comment: `awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%d ", i); printf("\n"); }' file`? Or if you only need the column numbers of the first row: `awk 'NR==1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%d ", i); printf("\n"); }' file`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, but it doesn't print the original column name. It only prints `1 2 3 ... 13`

Comment: Then make it `printf("%s ", $i);` instead

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried `awk 'NR==1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%d ", i); printf("%s ", $i); }' file`, `awk 'NR==1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n"); }' file`, `awk 'NR==1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%d ", i); printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s ", $i); }' file` and `awk 'NR==1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%d ", i); printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s ", $i); }' file` but none of them printed the expected output.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have it in the question as `(expected output)`.

Comment: By what rules do you want to make the transformation from the 3 lines of input to the expected 2 lines of output? If you can't describe that clearly, it's going to be a guessing game.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited the question (expected output part) and added a line after that to make it more clear.

Comment: please update the question with details on the input field delimiter ... tab? multiple spaces? fixed width?

Comment: @markp-fuso that's multiple spaces. I see your answer to replace `\t` with multiple spaces

Comment: is the intention to *maintain* the current spacing of the input line? or does spacing not matter as long as the columns are left-justified? would it suffice to reformat both lines with a tab delimiter?

Comment: @markp-fuso it doesn't matter because all columns are left aligned. It doesn't matter whether delimiter is tab or space, because in some real cases it may be either tab, or two spaces or four spaces.

Comment: @Saeed I've updated my answer; 2nd solution converts all white space (single space, multi-space, tab) to a single tab in the output; maintaining left-justification for longer columns requires more effort

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state how to get the output you show from the input you provided as it's not at all obvious.

Comment: In particular explain the 2 "8"s in the 2nd row of output.

Comment: Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559623/how-to-print-the-digit-number-of-column-in-awk#comment134986978_76559623) - it does matter. Do you want the values in the 2nd row to use the same spaces as the first row or to be visually aligned with the start of each column in the first row? If the first row has 2 cols like `thisisinteresting<tab>foo` should second row be `1<tab>2` (which will not visually align with the first row or `1<blanks to make 2 in second row appear under foo in first row>2` or `1<blanks to length of thisisinteresting><tab>2` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the first line only, so you can use `NR==1` to only run the block at the first line. You also need to remember the number of records on that line so I'll save that in the variable `fields` below.

```
awk 'NR==1 {
  fields=NF;
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%-7s ", $i);
  print ""; 
}
END {
  for(i=1; i <= fields; ++i) printf("%-7s ", i);
  print "";
}' file
```

The `END` block is executed when processing `file` is done.

If you don't want a separate `END` block, you could do it all in the block dealing with the first record:

```
awk 'NR==1 {
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%-7s ", $i);
  print "";
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%-7s ", i);
  print "";
}' file
```

- `printf("%-7s ", $i);` - This prints the *value* in the *i*:th column
- `printf("%-7s ", i);` - This prints the column number itself
- `-` in `-7s` makes it left justified
- `7` in `-7s` makes it take up 7 chars

Output with your input:

```
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input field delimiter is a tab (`\t`):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }                # define both input/output field delimiters
NR==1 { print                        # print current line
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i     # redefine each field as its numerical position in line
        print                        # print current line
        exit
      }
' file
```

This generates:

```
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

---

OP has since commented that the input field delimiter could be a mix of white spacing.

Assuming a reformat of the line to use tabs is acceptable:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }                        # only define output field delimiter
NR==1 { $1=$1                             # force reformat of input line
        print                             # print current line using new tab delimited output format
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i
        print
        exit
      }
' file
```

This (also) generates:

```
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

---

If a field is more than 7 characters in length then these solutions will not generate a *visible* left-alignment.

For example, assume the first column of line #1 is the string `col1_long_string` then both of these solutions will generate:

```
col1_long_string        |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

These lines are still tab delimited but the columns are (obviously) not visually left-aligned.

In this scenario - OP needs all columns left-aligned regardless of column width - it would be necessary to add more code.

For example, piping a simplified `awk` solution to `column -t`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i; print; exit}' file | column -t
col1_long_string  |  |  |  |  |  |  col2  -  -   -   -   col3
1                 2  3  4  5  6  7  8     9  10  11  12  13
```

**NOTE:** `column -t` will not work if a single column itself contains white space

A 100% `awk` solution (either maintain current spacing or modify spacing to insure all columns are left-aligned) is possible with a bit more coding, but we'll leave that for another Q&A ...

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf "%s ",$i; }; printf "\n";
       for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) { printf "%i ",i; }; printf "\n"}' input.txt
```

output, with given input:

```
col1 | | | | | | col2 - - - - col3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
this | | | | | | is - - - - good
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
that | | | | | | not - - - - bad
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

EDIT: With a small change the columns will align more (or better), that is they still will NOT keep the same with at the original input:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf "%s ",$i; }; printf "\n";
       for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) { printf "%-"length($i)"s ",i; }; printf "\n"}' input
```

output:

```
col1 | | | | | | col2 - - - - col3
1    2 3 4 5 6 7 8    9 10 11 12 13
this | | | | | | is - - - - good
1    2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11 12 13
that | | | | | | not - - - - bad
1    2 3 4 5 6 7 8   9 10 11 12 13
```

Comment: This seems to convert any `more than one space` or `\t` to `one space only`, which makes the output somehow not clear. If you can, please edit that so it won't manipulate the original delimiter.

Comment: @Saeed: Maybe you can put some (more) input of yourself into this, so you can have the output that your really want. and do **not** let others write **your** code!

Comment: I tried and am trying to see which part of your code I can edit:( I'm comparing your answer with Ted's to see where can I edit that, but I failed:(

Comment: @Saeed Our answers are very similar. Mine only prints the first line (since you said you would be doing `head -1 | awk ...`) and then it prints the column numbers. Luuks prints every line + the column numbers. If you want Luuks script to use the same formatting as you have in your expected output, just copy the `printf`s from my script into Luuk's and it should work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, `awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf "%-7s ",$i; }; printf "\n"; for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) { printf "%-7s ",i; }; printf "\n"}' file` worked too:)

Comment: @Saeed Yepp, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible interpretation of what you might be trying to do, using GNU awk for `FPAT` and `\S/\s`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='\\S+\\s*' -v OFS= '
    NR==1 { print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=sprintf("%-*s",length($i),i); print; exit }
' file
col1    |       |       |       |       |       |       col2    -       -       -       -       col3
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
```

It won't visually align with tabs correctly but neither will the answer you've accepted so I assume that's OK.